# Oracle task issue in having clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In the Having clause I am trying to compare 2 column because the condition is that CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT need to be multiply by 500 and compare with sum(s.amount_sold). Any ideas how to deal with this problem.

```
select (c.CUST_FIRST_NAME ||' '||c.CUST_LAST_NAME) as "CUSTOMER_NAME",
       to_number(substr(c.CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, -7, 8),'999999999') as "UPPER_INCOM_LEVEL",
       sum(s.amount_sold) as "TOTAL_AMOUNT",
       (case when c.CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT <=1500 then 'Low limit'
             when c.CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT >1500 then 'High limit'
        end) as "CREDIT_LIMIT_LEVEL",
       c.CUST_VALID
from sh.CUSTOMERS c JOIN sh.SALES s
on s.CUST_ID = c.CUST_ID
where CUST_VALID = 'A'
and CUST_INCOME_LEVEL like '%-%'
GROUP BY c.CUST_FIRST_NAME, c.CUST_LAST_NAME, s.AMOUNT_SOLD, c.CUST_INCOME_LEVEL, c.CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT, c.CUST_VALID
having s.amount_sold > c.CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT*500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to put the aggregation into a sub-query with just the `SALES` table and then `JOIN` the result of that to the `CUSTOMERS` table and can compare the credit limit to the sales amount in the join condition (and remove the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses from the outer query):

```sql
SELECT c.cust_first_name || ' ' || c.cust_last_name AS customer_name,
       TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(c.cust_income_level, -7), '9999999') AS upper_income_level,
       s.total_amount,
       CASE
       WHEN c.cust_credit_limit <= 1500
       THEN 'Low Limit'
       WHEN c.cust_credit_limit >  1500
       THEN 'High Limit'
       END AS credit_limit_level,
       c.cust_valid
FROM   sh.customers c
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT cust_id,
                SUM(amount_sold) AS total_amount
         FROM   sh.sales
         GROUP BY cust_id
       ) s
       ON (   c.cust_id = s.cust_id
          AND s.total_amount > c.cust_credit_limit * 500 )
WHERE  c.cust_valid = 'A'
AND    c.cust_income_level LIKE '%-%'            -- Check for a hyphen anywhere
-- AND SUBSTR(c.cust_income_level, -8, 1) = '-'  -- Check for a hyphen in a specific place
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you said (looks like you're missing the `sum` aggregate function in your `having` clause) (also, you should put all non-aggregated columns into the `group by` clause; yours contains `s.amount_sold`, while it shouldn't):

```
group by c.cust_first_name, 
         c.cust_last_name,
         substr(c.cust_income_level, -7, 8),
         case when c.cust_credit_limit <= 1500 then 'Low limit'
              when c.cust_credit_limit >  1500 then 'High limit'
         end,
         c.cust_valid
having sum(s.amount_sold) > c.cust_credit_limit * 500
```